# Varnish vcl_error should exclude static files for maintenance

Tags: varnish

When you need a maintenance site in your Varnish, the default way is to serve it via sub vcl_error() by calling `error 503`.

The problem here is, when you need js/css/images in your maintenance site and they are hosted on the same URL, as all of this files will end up in a 503 too.

Is there a way to exclude specific files or files by file extension? I tried several ways, e.g. placing an if() statement around the error 503 and just enter it if file extension is not png,jpg,js,css. But it leads to a timeout.

Most time i've been reading, that placing files on e.g. Cloudflare or use base64 encoding for images and inline css/js if needed.

Are these the only ways?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are right, base64 encoded images and inline css, js, etc... is safest bet.

- whole response is single atomic payload
- you don't need to clutter your vcl with such corner cases
- no way to directly visits assets by crawlers
- no risk of cache propagation of maintenance assets to sites out of control (forward proxies)

and on and on.

BTW, you don't have to put html file inside vcl, you could use this statement:

```
synthetic std.fileread("/etc/varnish/error.html");
```

and all you need is single inline html from design department.

Comment: The problem here is, that inline all files including images as base64 encoded will blow the maintenance.html from around 1KiB to nearly 1.5MiB in a single file. But thanks for answering, i will give you the answer vote. Thanks!

Comment: Thank you :) Well, you have to review your maintenance page then. I think anything above 100kB is too large for this purpose. Think about all those mobile users with poorer connection. And waiting seconds just to realize site is down will make them really upset I'm afraid.

Comment: Oh my customer (and his customers too) are very addicted to style the site. Even the maintenance site is a styled site with a really cool background picture ;) And as you have to define things for crossbrowser you have to use prefiixed css with background picture data/src in base64 encoded format. So it's rather easy to hit a megabyte soon.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, i've found a workaround that works for me now.

In the HTML code, that represents the maintenance site, i've used URLs including the backend port. So the requests won't hit the Varnish itself but the Apache server.